# Google chart y axis not ordered properly

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm having an issue with Google bar chart. It doesn't put y-axis values in order (Figure A). The other issue is that it shows bars even if the values are zeros (Figure B).

Please see my code below :

```
success: function (r) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    var newData = r.d;

    // determine the number of rows and columns.
    var numRows = newData.length;

    if (numRows > 0) {
        var numCols = newData[0].length;

        // in this case the first column is of type 'string'.
        data.addColumn('string', newData[0][0]);

        // all other columns are of type 'number'.
        for (var i = 1; i < numCols; i++)
            data.addColumn('string', newData[0][i]);

        // now add the rows.
        for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++)
            data.addRow(newData[i]);
    }
    else {

        data.addColumn('string', "Category");
        data.addColumn('number', "No Data");
        data.addRow(null);
    }

    var options = {
        bars: 'vertical',  
        height: 350,
        bar: { groupWidth: "40" },
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        chartArea: { 'width': '50%', 'height': '100%' }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

}
```

Figure A

[image: Figure A]

Figure B

[image: Figure B]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens when string values are used, instead of numbers...

here, the comment mentions using number, but the code has string

```
// all other columns are of type 'number'.
for (var i = 1; i < numCols; i++)
    data.addColumn('string', newData[0][i]);
```

try changing to the following...

```
// all other columns are of type 'number'.
for (var i = 1; i < numCols; i++)
    data.addColumn('number', parseFloat(newData[0][i]));
```